# Applescript droplet doesn't run another handler

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to make a droplet script in Applescript using the code below.

I have a handler which runs a command line with the POSIX path of the selected file.

When I run the script everything works (my command line handler works fine). But, if I drop the file to my script, nothing happens.

I need some help, please

```
on run
   set thePath to POSIX path of (choose file of type "img" default location (path to downloads folder from user domain))
   doIt(thePath)
end run

on open myImageFile
    tell application "Finder"
        if (count of myImageFile) is greater than 1 then
            display alert "A message" as critical
        else if name extension of item 1 of myImageFile is not "img"  then
            display alert "A message" as critical
        else
            set thePath to POSIX path of item 1 of myImageFile
            doIt(thePath)
        end if
    end tell
end open
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line: `doIt(thePath)` in the open handler into: `my  doIt(thePath)`.

The reason for the error, is that you try to use your handler from within the scope of finder, and finder, doesn't reckognize it as something of its own. Therefore you must add `my`in front of it, so the handler can be resolved.